# Occur Exception when I used hibernate-types-52 JsonBinaryType in Multi module project

Tags: spring, jpa, hibernate-types

I used hibernate-52 in multi-module Project.
project's structure consist of root, core and api.

JPA entity, repository is defined in core.

```
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class TestEntity {
    @Id private Long id;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private List<TestType> data;
}
```

when i append implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.3' to root dependency, occured exception below Message

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule Unable to get public no-arg constructor
```

and when i tear off dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.3, up and running

why occurred exception, when i append dependency 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.3

#### root dependency

implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.1'

#### core dependency

implementation 'com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.4.3'